# Disable Redis on Admin

Tags: backend, redis

I have some issues with saving products on back-end, esp on the images. The issues occur right after I have enabled Redis. On front-end, however, Redis is working well.

Is it possible to enable Redis only on front-end and disable it on Admin?

Answer (score 0):

You can not disable REDIS In admin. You will need to change your Local.xml file and comment our your REDIS info.

You can clear and refresh REDIS from Admin